# auto-refresh dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlist that is populated with values from the db. I want the dropdownlist to be auto refreshed every 5min, without refreshing the page. How can I achieve this?

I tried making an ajax call to the action that has the dropdownlist but that's not right because it refreshes the entire page. Here is the code snippet:

Controller/action
           //GET

```
  public ActionResult Index()
            {
        InternalViewModel app = new InternalViewModel();                                
        app.totalclients = db2.AppClients.Count();
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db2.AppClients, "ClientID",      "ClientName", app.clientid);    //for the dropdownlist to display clients   
        return View(app);
    }
```

View:

```
        @Html.DropDownList("Clientid", ViewBag.ClientID as SelectList, "--Select Client--", new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    @id = "dropdown2",
})
        </div>
    </div>
```

The dropdown on change performs certain actions, so I'm not able to find a way to automatically refresh the dropdown without refreshing the entire page. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could make an ajax call to the page's action, retrieve the whole html, then extract just the bit you're interested in from the resulting html.  Or you could put the dropdownlist in a partial and ajax just the partial - the partial could be reused on your page.

Comment: you can use `setInterval(function(){ your ajax call }, 50000);` this will make ajax call in every 5 min

Comment: @freedomn-m : Thanks, I used that idea and put the dropdownlist in a partial view and refreshed it every 5 seconds. It's solved :)

Comment: @BharatPatidar: Thank you. I used setInterval to make the ajax call :)

Comment: you are welcome :)